# Jquery | XML loading by name or id only

Tags: jquery, xml, load

I'm new to Jquery and I'm trying add a function that will load the id or name of the xml only once. Here's an example, where I have "name" I would like to only load those sections into an div id, not an array. Thanks, I hope this makes sense.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<newslinks>

    <news name="fs_img" imageurl="news/2011/01/w01/imgs/banner1_thumb.jpg">
        <url1>news/2011/01/w01/imgs/banner1.jpg</url1>
        <alt1>Headline 1</alt1>
        <date name="fs_date" >01/01/11</date>
        <headline name="fs_hl" >Headline 1 Story</headline>
        <url2 name="fs_hll" >#/url2>
        <headlinelink name="fs_hlls">Headline 1 Story Link</headlinelink>
    </news>

    <news imageurl="news/2011/01/w01/imgs/banner2_thumb.jpg">
        <url1>news/2011/01/w01/imgs/banner2.jpg</url1>
        <alt1>Headline 2</alt1>
        <date>01/01/11</date>
        <headline>Headline 2 Story</headline>
        <url2>#</url2>
       <headlinelink>Headline 2 Story Link</headlinelink>
    </news> 




</newslinks>
```

Comment: Please post an exmample of your expected result to further clarify your question.  Thanks.  Also, why do you have two closing news elements?  Can you fix that too?  This highlights why code formatting and proper indentation is so important.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var news = $("[name='fs_img']");
```

Untested but i think it should work.

or

```
    $("[name='fs_img']").each(function(){ 
      //do something with the element 
      //$(this)......
    });
```